# Phonegap new version for suitable db location in IOS app development

Tags: android, iphone, objective-c, ios, cordova

I am using IOS 5.1 with Phone-gap 1.3 and it seems, by default phonegap looks into ../Library/Caches folder for a database. I want to upgrade to a suitable higher version like 1.8 or 2.0. Do these new versions support finding the db by default in ../Documents dir because this is a preferable location and not /caches dir since IOS can anytime delete data from /Cache when encountering low memory problems.

Which is a suitable version of phone-gap considering the above mentioned point plus I have android platform also using the same phone-gap code.?
Any suggestions are most welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2.1 (the latest) still stores the files in the same location but solves the problem of files getting deleted. For iOS 5.1 it takes a backup of the database. For iOS 6 it sets a property that tells iOS to keep the databases and web content.

Until the next release you probably want to get the latest source from GitHub since the 2.1 release has a small bug where localStorage data is not persisted the first time you run the application. From the second time onwards everything is fine.

**EDIT**

This bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-330 talks about the issue in 5.1 and how PhoneGap work around it.

**EDIT AGAIN**

This bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1535 details the code fix required to make localStorage data persist from the first install on iOS 6.

Comment: so u mean IOS 5.1 will detect the phone-gap version 2.1 and not delete the files from /Caches because IOS is the one which deletes the files.

Comment: added link to answer which explains how PhoneGap deals with files being deleted

Comment: Does it mean that for phone-gap 2.1 i will have to use the plug-in given in the link to store data in back-up because i have to support IOS5.1 or lower.SO, IOS 6 IS OUT OF question. There is no way without the plug-in?

Comment: The plugin is only if you are using PhoneGap 1.6 or older. That functionality is baked in as part of later versions. So 2.1 already includes that functionality.

Comment: Since 2.1 u say has a bug, so i think best would be 2.0. And in objective-c i believe i have to copy db files in /Caches folder only and phone-gap will then take care that back-up of files is used when IOS deletes files from /Caches folder. Am i on the same page?

Comment: You should use 2.1 since it has more fixes, especially for iOS 6. The one small bug has an easy fix that you can easily make in the code since from 2.0 onwards Cordova is included as a sub-project. You are correct that Cordova will take care of backing up and restoring your databases/localStorage

Comment: So i installed 2.1.0 and, now i have to paste my code and see if it is working fine. @code monkey... Can u help me in fixing that small bug in 2.1.0 because its really urgent and I don't have much time for debugging. Ur help is appreciated.Thanks